# low space disk on file root system

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, swap, disk-usage, disk

I had created root file system partition of 30 GB and almost 3 swap partitions. Now it say low space disk.I have tried to delete the swap partition and increase the root file system and it shows that the space has been increased using lsblk but still the space has not been increased.

How can I fix this I have been using ubuntu 23.04 Desktop?
[image][image]

[image: lsblk]

[image: low file root systemstrong text]

Comment: You have a 931G device but only about 600G is in use. Where is the unused space? A picture of the GParted screen with your disk selected might help. What is the output of df -h ? Please add this to your question. It sounds like you haven’t expanded the filesystem after changing the size of the disk but how did you do this? Usually you would do this in a live environment

Comment: I have added gparted ss as well. And regarding how I made those changes I followed this article...https://tekneed.com/increase-standard-extend-root-partition-using-fdisk/

Comment: In your question you said your root partition is 30GB but lsblk shows it as about 342G. Is the 30GB a typo? Did you complete the `resize2fs /dev/sda8` step without errors? What you describe in the question suggests you didn’t. The `df -h` command will tell us the filesystem size and that can be compared with the partition size

Comment: I have had completed all the process but still ' df -h ' shows that I have not completed and the space is not increased.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have had tried all steps before but don't know how but I once again used your given commands to resize and the size has been increased which can be seen by 'df -h' command.

Comment: Happy to help. Glad you got it fixed. You can answer your own question with the steps you took to resolve it. 24 hours later you can accept the answer. That way other’s with a similar problem will have a better chance of finding the answer. This is not an uncommon problem. I’ve seen it several times